# Запрос в MySQL через PHP

Tags: php, запрос, mysql

Доброго времени суток! Сделал форму с запросом и функцию записи в БД, но он вносит пустые значения. Что не так?

Собственно исходник:

Форма

```
<form action="zapros.php" method="post" name="form">
Имя: <input type="text" name"name"><br>
Год: <input type="text" name"year"><br>
Хозяин: <input type="text" name"xoz"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Запрос" name="submit">
</form>
```

обработчик запроса:

```
<?
$name = $_POST['name'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$xoz = $_POST['xoz'];
$db = mysql_connect ("localhost","test","12345");
mysql_select_db("test",$db);
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO names (name,year,xoz) VALUES ('$name','$year','$xoz')");
if ($result == 'true')
{
echo "Успешно!";
}
else
{
echo "Неудачно!";
}
?>
```

Comment: 1. Покажите форму или хотя бы полностью открывающий тег <form> со всеми его атрибутами.
2. Данные формы отправляются в отдельный файл-обработчик или на эту же страницу?
3. В какой кодировке ваши документы?
4. В примере не видно, но экранируете ли вы данные?
5. Пробывали ли вы выводить на экран "прилетевшие" переменные из POST-запроса? Если да, то были ли там данные?

Comment: @bazaev05, вы как-то не заметили еще четыре наводящих вопроса ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите внимательней ваш код формы.
У вас везде name"name" а равно забыли? :) 
Надо так name**=**"name".

P.S. Запомните пожалуйста как 2*2, ВСЕ данные приходяшие от пользователя НАДО ЭКРАНИРОВАТЬ!
Для WEB-программиста нет более страшной ошибки чем $name = $_POST['name'];

Answer (score 1):

Для начала - откуда вы набрались такой пошлости? )) Неужели опять Попов-detected?

```
if ($result == 'true') {
   // ...
}
```

Достаточно просто:

```
if ($result) {
   // ...
}
```

Во-вторых, пробуйте сделать следующее в файле обработчике:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['year'], $_POST['xoz'])){
    $db = mysql_connect ("localhost","test","12345");
    mysql_select_db("test",$db);

    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $year = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['year']);
    $xoz= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['xoz']);

    $query = "INSERT INTO names (name,year,xoz) VALUES ('$name','$year','$xoz')";
    echo $query;
} else {
    echo "А запросик то и не долетел!";
}
```

Если все нормально, то смотрим на то, в какой кодировке отображаются данные. Если с кодировкой все гуд, то убираем echo $query; и пишем запрос:

```
// ... 
$query = "INSERT INTO names (name,year,xoz) VALUES ('$name','$year','$xoz')";
$result = mysql_query($query, $db);
// ...
```

Кстати, забыл поинтересоваться какая кодировка у вас в БД?